# same Ajax call behaving differently inside a .net project

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, .net-4.0

I have a simple webform with an ajax call, which executes flawlessly, however when I put the same code into an existing project, the ajax call refreshes the page.  The project was .net 2.0 converted to .net 4.0.  Here is the simple code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="5000" ontick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer> 



    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" 
    Height="118px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="468px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" 
    onclick="Button1_Click" /><br /><br />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">

    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="120px" 
        TextMode="MultiLine" Width="466px"></asp:TextBox>
    </ContentTemplate>

    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick"/>
    </Triggers>

</asp:UpdatePanel> 


    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

cs code: 
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Save();
        }

```
    private void Save()
    {
        //Add the save function here ex store the text to DB
        //Here we only move between the two textboxes to show that it works
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    }
    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Save();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update.  I found the issue, this line:
**xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy"**
was added to webconfig during conversion from .net 2.0.

Commenting this line fixes the ajax refresh.